# Can not connect to mongodb after replica?

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I always get this error trying to connect to the Mongodb

**MongoDB Response**

> server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetN
> oPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: mongodb:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup mongodb: no such host }, ] }

**MongoDB Log**

> mongodb      | 2022-03-08T06:40:26.387+0000 I NETWORK  [conn14]
> received client metadata from 172.25.0.1:39218 conn14: { driver: {
> name: "mongo-go-driver", version: "v1.8.3" }, os: { type: "windows",
> architecture: "amd64" }, platform: "go1.17.5" }

---

Here is how I set up

docker-compoes.yml

```
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    build: ./mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGODB_USER=debezium
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=dbz
    networks:
      - pg-es-synch_default
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:3.6
CMD ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0", "--auth"]
```

Command

```
>> mongo localhost:27017/ecommerce_connect
rs.initiate({
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [ { _id: 0, host: "mongodb:27017" } ]
});

>> mongo localhost:27017/admin
db.createUser({ user: 'admin', pwd: 'admin', roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] });


>> mongo -u admin -p admin localhost:27017/admin
db.createUser({
    user: 
    'debezium',
    pwd: 'dbz',
    roles: [
        { role: "readWrite", db: "ecommerce_connect" },
        { role: "readWrite", db: "local" },
        { role: "root", db: "admin" },
        { role: "readWrite", db: "config" },
    ]
});
```

When I login by user `debezium` outside Docker in the localhost I always got the error mentioned above.

But if I do this in CLI of Docker, It works

```
>> mongo -u debezium -p dbz --authenticationDatabase admin localhost:27017/ecommerce_connect  
use ecommerce_connect;
db.product_info.insert([
    { _id : NumberLong("128"), name : 'scooter', description: 'Small 2-wheel scooter', weight : 3.14, quantity : NumberInt("3") }
]);
```

I connect to `mongoDB` by this URL:

`"mongodb://debezium:dbz@localhost:27017"`

Comment: A password with only three(!) letters for the root account?

Comment: After `rs.initiate()` you should wait till Replica Set is initiated, e.g. append `while (! db.isMaster().ismaster ) { sleep(1000) }`

Comment: You grant role `{ role: "root", db: "admin" }` which grants **all** privileges to the user. Thus any other role is redundant.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am using Debezium which only work with Replica Sets, would you mind including what are roles that missing if I want to to have full access

Comment: You granted already full access, there is nothing more - apart from [`__system`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-__system) role which you should never grant by default.